# How to restrict over shipment at customer shipment in EPICOR ERP

Tags: business-process-management, epicorerp

I want to restrict user from entering job ship quantity greater then order quantity at customer shipment level in EPICOR Erp.

Created a BPM custom code to check the values and to display a message if there is over shipment. It works fine for the first time. That means while creating a new pack slip and if I am entering job ship quantity more than requested quantity it works fine. But when I unchecked the shipped checkbox then actions->open(ed the shipment) and entered job ship quantity greater than requested quantity the BPM Code does not working.

```
var ShipDtl = ttShipDtl.Where(sd => (sd.Added()) && ((sd.OurJobShipQty + sd.OurInventoryShipQty) > (sd.SellingReqQty - sd.SellingShippedQty))).FirstOrDefault();

if(ShipDtl != null){
    var msg = "You are attempting to overship. Please correct before you can continue.";
    msg = msg + ShipDtl.SellingReqQty + " " + ShipDtl.SellingShippedQty + " " + ShipDtl.OurJobShipQty + " " + ShipDtl.OurInventoryShipQty;
    throw new Ice.Common.BusinessObjectException(
        new Ice.Common.BusinessObjectMessage(msg){
            Type = Ice.Common.BusinessObjectMessageType.Error,
        }
    );
}
```

**Expected result:**

An error message if user enters job ship quantity greater than requested quantity(IN full and partial shipment cases of an order)

Comment: What version specifically of Epicor are you using?

Comment: @Pants:-Epicor10.2.200

Comment: Per your code, it seems you have it setup to only do the check when its first added. `ttShipDtl.Where(sd => (sd.Added()` based off your description of the events that took place it sounds like you made an Update after you created/saved the record. Which would explain why it didn't fire.

Comment: can you just provide the code to check the quantity after update.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first line to the following, which should fix the problem:

```
var ShipDtl = ttShipDtl.Where(sd => (sd.Added() || sd.Updated()) && ((sd.OurJobShipQty + sd.OurInventoryShipQty) > (sd.SellingReqQty - sd.SellingShippedQty))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your current code specifically is selecting shipping lines only as they are added, but not as they are updated.  The `sd.Updated()` similarly selects lines where `RowMod == IceRow.ROWSTATE_UPDATED`